# Why doesn't my collision detection/update score work on my game?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

So I'm making a simple 2d endless runner like the chrome dino game for a small project. It's very basic and I want it to update the score by one each time the player successfully jumps over the obstacle.

When I tried to implement my collision detection t was supposed to detect the obstacle if the player missed it and either end the game (which i haven't done yet) or update the score. Here's the code.

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');
const scoreValue = document.getElementById('score-value');
let score = 0

function updateScore() {
    score++;
    scoreValue.innerText = score;
}

function moveObstacle() {
    const speed = 5
    let obstaclePosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue('right'));

    if (obstaclePosition < window.innerWidth) { 
        obstacle.style.right = `${obstaclePosition + speed}px`
    } else {
        obstacle.style.right = '0';
    }

    detectCollision();
}

function jump() {
    if (!player.classList.contains('jump')) {
        player.classList.add('jump');

        setTimeout(() => {
             player.classList.remove('jump') 
        }, 500);
    }
}

function detectCollision() {
    let playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
    let obstacleRect = obstacle.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (playerRect.left < obstacleRect.right &&
        playerRect.right > obstacleRect.left &&
        playerRect.top < obstacleRect.bottom &&
        playerRect.bottom > obstacleRect.top) {
        // Collision detected, update the score
        updateScore();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        jump();
    }
});

setInterval(moveObstacle, 20);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#game-container { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#player { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#obstacle { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#score { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.jump { 
    transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Endless Runner Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-container">
        <div id="player"></div>
        <div id="obstacle"></div>
        <div id="score">Score: <span id="score-value">0</span></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then click the button with `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: I question this logic `// Collision detected, update the score` - it seems like you get points for hitting things.

Comment: Your collision detection will be run even if there isn't currently an obstacle to collide with, so by itself it cannot determine if the player jumped over an obstacle.  You need some logic that checks 1) did an obstacle just scroll past, and 2) is the player still alive = jump points.

Answer (score 1):

Your collision detection works fine. But you want to detect jumps,
which should be defined geometrically by only the x coordinates overlapping and the y coordinates *not* overlapping.

So you have to slightly adjust the logic of your code, to separate x overlapping conditions form y overlapping. You should keep track of
what's happening with these conditions, in boolean variables, so you avoid repeating the same actions during the same event. For instance, if a collision is detected, there could be no score update in that pass.

And you logic should take into consideration obstacle "passes" - a pass
begins from the moment the obstacle is placed to the right and ends at the next moment it is placed to the right - in such a pass there will always be either a score increment, or a collision; thus all variables should be reset when the obstacle is reset to the right.

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');
const scoreValue = document.getElementById('score-value');
const collisionsValue = document.getElementById('collisions-value');
let score = 0, collisions = 0;

function updateScore() {
    score++;
    scoreValue.innerText = score;
}

function updateCollisions() {
    collisions++;
    collisionsValue.innerText = collisions;
}


let jumpStarted = false, jumpFull = false, collision = false; 
function moveObstacle() {
    const speed = 5
    let obstaclePosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue('right'));

    if (obstaclePosition < window.innerWidth) { 
        obstacle.style.right = `${obstaclePosition + speed}px`
    } else {
        obstacle.style.right = '0';
        if(jumpStarted && !collision && !jumpFull){
           // jumpFull failed to register for lack of space 
           updateScore();
        }
        // reset jump logic each time the obstacle is repositioned at right
        jumpStarted = false;
        jumpFull = false;
        collision = false;
    }

    detectCollision();
}

function jump() {
    if (!player.classList.contains('jump')) {
        player.classList.add('jump');

        setTimeout(() => {
             player.classList.remove('jump') 
        }, 500);
    }
}

function detectCollision() {
    if(collision || jumpFull){
      return;
    }
    let playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
    let obstacleRect = obstacle.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (playerRect.left < obstacleRect.right &&
          playerRect.right > obstacleRect.left){
        if( playerRect.top < obstacleRect.bottom && 
            playerRect.bottom > obstacleRect.top){
          collision = true;
          updateCollisions();
          return;
        }
        jumpStarted = true;
    }
    else if(jumpStarted){
      jumpFull = true;
      updateScore();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        jump();
    }
});

setInterval(moveObstacle, 20);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#game-container { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

#player { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#obstacle { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#score { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.jump { 
    transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Endless Runner Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-container">
        <div id="player"></div>
        <div id="obstacle"></div>
        <div id="score">Score: <span id="score-value">0</span>
        &nbsp; Collisions: <span id="collisions-value">0</span>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```